# How do I sort articles by article order in Joomla 3?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, com-content, category, category-blog

I've got a category with two sub-categories, the articles appear to be **grouped** in the back end by *sub-category* and it doesn't allow me to set the article order to mix them.  Is this normal?

It's not how I understood it to work.

Is there a setting that allows me to set an arbitrary order?

This means in the front end that I see articles sorted by article order within category, even when I set **category** order to no order in the menu.

Comment: In order to do that it would require assigning Joomla articles to multiple categories (subcat1 + subcat2) - which isn't possible. http://bit.ly/2dZHrZI - this gives a number of workarounds - using a cck such as http://www.flexicontent.org/ - enables articles to have multiple categories.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the Administrator panel -> Menus -> Main Menu -> go to the tab Blog Layout

and find there Article Order - Oldest first, or setup other settings would you like.

[image: joomla]

Your admin link will look like this:

http: //your-site.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_menus&view=item&layout=edit&id=101

Comment: I've tried every setting in the menu.  Article Order doesn't change the fact that articles are displayed within category, and that I can't set an order in the articles page that mixes articles from different categories.

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround is to use the Featured Articles feature. You can set your articles as featured from any kind of category and then use a Featured Articles menu item to display with your desired featured articles order.